# knockout js -- best way to assign attributes to model via script / programmatically?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, attributes, self

How can I programmatically assign knockout js attributes to a view model?

I need some kind of factory structure, but I'm not sure about the best way to go about it...

I'm trying to assign attributes that don't exist yet to a model..

I want to reduce this:

```
 function aViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.attr1Text = ko.observable("");
        self.attr1Text.focused = ko.observable(false);
        self.attr2Text = ko.observable("");
        self.attr2Text.focused = ko.observable(false);
        self.attr3Text = ko.observable("");
        self.attr3Text.focused = ko.observable(false);
        self.attr4Text = ko.observable("");
        self.attr4Text.focused = ko.observable(false);
        self.attr5Text = ko.observable("");
        self.attr5Text.focused = ko.observable(false);
}
vm = new aViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

to something like this:

```
    function aViewModel(attrs) {
            var self = this;

            for (var attr of attrs){
                self[attr+"Text"] = ko.observable("");
                self[attr+"Text"]["focused"] = ko.observable(false);
            }
    }

   attr_list = ["attr1", "attr2", ..., "attrN"]
   vm = new aViewModel(attr_list);
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And have it actually work.

This works:

```
    function aViewModel() {
            var self = this;
    }


   vm = new aViewModel();
    attr_list = ["attr1", "attr2", ..., "attrN"]
   for (var attr of attr_list){
       self[attr+"Text"] = ko.observable("");
       self[attr+"Text"]["focused"] = ko.observable(false);
   }
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

But more encapsulation would be nice so I just created a wrapper function,

```
function createGrid(things, data){
    vm = new gridViewModel(things);
    for (var thing of things){
        vm[thing+"Text"] = ko.observable("");
        vm[thing+"Text"]["focused"] = ko.observable(false);
    }
    \\ other stuff with data
    return vm;
}
```

then used

```
  vm = createGrid(things, data)
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I feel like I'm answering my own question. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I can smell a bit of [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) here. If you can control the `things` that is passed, then surely this can be done via ko.mapping.

Answer (score 0):

use the [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin

```
var modelClass = function(data){
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data,this);
  //additional values or computed
  this.full_name = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.unwrap(this.first_name) + '  ' + ko.unwrap(this.last_name);
  }
}
var mapping = {
  create : function(options){
    return new modelClass(options.data);
  }
}

var viewModel = function(){
  this.myModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping);
}
```